# Bootstrap, align input with label to button without label, vertical form / not horizontal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to align input with label, to button without label, using bootstrap v3 with default form (vertical, not horizontal layout of form).

Desired effect: http://screencast.com/t/b2uwBopW9rW

I managed to solve this by creating label with non-breaking space inside label, but I wonder if there is more clean, better way to achieve this effect.

Example on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r6o5hysk/1/

```
<div class='container' style='width:200px; margin: 50px;'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                Name
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>
              &nbsp;
              <div class="btn btn-danger">Remove</div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bootstrap is a great structure in which you can create any kind of html just you need to understand the structure. Always try to use only bootstrap classes but not the external things.

Check this bootstrap only structure with the desired output

```
<div class='container' style='width:200px; margin: 50px;'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <label>Name</label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn btn-danger">Remove</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/r6o5hysk/2/

Comment: this breaks with multiple input fields

Comment: This falls apart with a responsive layout where the columns collapse

Answer (score 19):

Adding margins is not the best idea. What if the `label` `font-size` changes? You'll need to adjust the `margin` as well.

Make the `button` to act as a `block`

```css
.btn.btn-as-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='container'>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="btn btn-danger btn-as-block">Remove</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Best solution compared to the accepted solution. No more loads of code heap.

Comment: you can use built in .d-block class instead of making own class. Works as good.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a little bit late because the OP was from 2015 but anyway, it maybe useful for somebody using the newest [Bootstrap 4.3.1](https://getbootstrap.com).

Actually you do not need to include any extra CSS or do any kind of complex tweaks, just taking advantage of how `row`, `form-row`, `col` classes behave side by side and how its `padding` and `margins` coexist each other is enough.

This is the structure you need to follow make it work:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
  <form>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="name">User data:</label>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Alex Ventura">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="alexventuraio">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Contact</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I hope it could give an idea to anyone else with the same problem. Here is [my pen](https://codepen.io/alexventuraio/pen/LwbgWZ) just for further reference.

Comment: ***macabre*** (adjective): *"disturbing because concerned with or causing a fear of death"*. Which of the existing answers makes you afraid you'll die, Alex?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu sorry for being exaggerated I just wanted to emphasize any strange or arduous tricks to accomplish it! ;)

Comment: What if you had third input with a label? Maybe I'm wrong, but as far as I see, this approach isn't really flexible. It's basically a label with everything else in a different block element.

Comment: @scrnjakovic you’re right, that may not work, but I think that the OP didn’t ask what you are asking. This is only one more approach for the scenario that the OP asked for, that’s it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, no need for extra divs or `&nbsp;`.

I have kept the `<label>` field for the Name only since logically an input field is not a label.

No need for div `<div class="form-group">` it just applies extra margin.

I have added a class alignment to the button, and setup `margin-top` to align.

```css
.alignment
{
    margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container' style='width:200px; margin: 50px;'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-10">
            <label>
                Name
            </label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="btn btn-danger alignment">Remove</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This breaks the responsive nature of the form.

Answer (score 1):

You actually just have to put the `label` outside of the `form-group`. To overcome the responsive behavior of `form-group` add `display:inline-block` to the element. Added `marge-left`to the `button`to create the gap between the `input` and the `button`.

```css
.forceInlineBlock {
   display: inline-block; 
}
.addLeftMargin25 {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline">
  <label for="name">Name</label><br />
  <div class="form-group forceInlineBlock">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  />
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger addLeftMargin25">Remove</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know OP asked (long time ago) for BS3, but for those who stumbled upon this thread and are looking for BS4 solution (given you use SCSS), you can use following code to create `mt-label mt-lg-label ...` etc classes and use them on controls without labels

```
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
        $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);

        .mt#{$infix}-label {
            margin-top: $label-margin-bottom + ($line-height-base * $font-size-base);
        }
    }
}
```

As long as your labels inherit it's font-size and line-height from the body (which they do in BS4 by default) and you increase font-size using variables (like you shoud), it will account for the font-size changes.