# Align button with input forms with labels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I'm trying to align a button element with two other input elements with labels. Using the bootstrap snippet below:

```
<div class="row centered-form center-block ">
  <div class="container col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <form action="/result" class="form-inline" method="get" role="form">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
           <label class="control-label" for="County">Prop1, Prop2</label>
           <input class="form-control" name="County"  type="text" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-4">
           <label class="control-label" for="Type">Type of Election</label>
             <select class="form-control" name="Type"><option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">President</option>
             </select>
         </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-2" type="submit">Submit</button>
     </div>
   </form>    
  </div>
</div>
```

The image I'm getting looks like this:

[image]

If I remove labels from the two from inputs, I get:

[image]

How can I leave labels on the form inputs and still align them with the button?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeLhxrja/)

Comment: Can you provide a complete working example? I test the code and it looks ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap, align input with label to button without label, vertical form / not horizontal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214255/bootstrap-align-input-with-label-to-button-without-label-vertical-form-not-h)

Comment: @Dekel I added a fiddle. Exactly the same code I have in IDE, but a different result in Fiddle.

Comment: first you need to give 100% width to the input, because its overlapping the colums , and second one you dont have to set empty label just add `padding-top` or `margin-top` to the button,

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of an improper label, use the `align-self-end` class (bootstrap 4 / flexbox) to vertically align the button to the bottom of the column.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2 align-self-end">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" name="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Worked for me. Another way that I tried and seems to work is applying style="margin-top: auto" to div hosting the button.

Comment: Doesn't work if you have a validation message written beneath the field

Answer (score 1):

I believe button classes don't work that way.

Updated: This is silly but it works. And if it works, don't mess with it!

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label class="control-label" for="btn"></label>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" name="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not fix it. Check fiddle.

Comment: @hello I updated the code snipet. Adding an empty label to the button brings it exactly where it should be. Deffinitely not the best practice but it works!

Comment: @Yuri that was just a solution for this specific case, not something general. Maybe you could try align to the bottom of the div or smth